# An allowed character is being percent encoded

Tags: swift

Documentation for the string method `addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:)`:

> Returns a new string made from the receiver by replacing all characters not in the specified set with percent-encoded characters.

The predefined set `CharacterSet.alphanumerics` says:

> Returns a character set containing the characters in Unicode General Categories L*, M*, and N*.

The `L` (*Letter*) category  consists of 5 subcategories: `Ll`,`Lm`,`Lt`,`Lu`,`Lo`. So I assume `L*` means all of L's subcategories.

I'll choose to look at the `Ll` subcategory (https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Ll#UNC_SCRIPTS), and pick the character `"æ"` (U+00E6).
I can then see that the alphanumerics character set indeed contains this character. But when I add percent encoding to a string containing this character, it gets percent encoded.

```
"\u{E6}" // "æ"
CharacterSet.alphanumerics.contains("\u{E6}") // true
"æ".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics) // "%C3%A6" 

// Let's try with "a"
"\u{61}" // "a"
CharacterSet.alphanumerics.contains("\u{61}") // true
"a".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics) // "a"
```

Why does this happen? It's in the allowed character set that I passed in, so it shouldn't be replaced, right?

I feel like it has something to do with the fact that `"a"` (U+0061) is also `0x61` in `UTF-8` but `"æ"` (U+00E6) is `[0xC3, 0xA6]`; not `0xE6`. Or that it takes up more than 1 byte?

```
String(data: Data([0x61]), encoding: .utf8)! // "a"
String(data: Data([0xC3, 0xA6]), encoding: .utf8)! // "æ"
String(data: Data([0xE6]), encoding: .utf8)! // crashes
```

**Update**

Is it because the percent encoding algorithm converts the string to `Data` and goes through 1 byte at a time? so it'll look at `0xC3` which isn't an allowed character, so that gets percent encoded. Then it'll look at `0xA6` which also isn't an allowed character, so that gets percent encoded too. So allowed characters technically have to be a single byte?

Comment: [The last paragraph](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411946-addingpercentencoding#discussion) in the documentation of that method states: "UTF-8 encoding is used to determine the correct percent-encoded characters. Any characters in allowedCharacters outside of the 7-bit ASCII range are ignored."

Comment: @alobaili **"Any characters in allowedCharacters outside of the 7-bit ASCII range are ignored."** this answers the question

Comment: @alobaili Ahh, I missed that. Thanks 

Comment: If the problem is trivially solved please delete the question. Or you can answer your own question of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *truly* allowed character has to be in the allowed character set, *and* be an ASCII character. Thanks @alobaili for pointing that out.

If you're curious, the predefined set `CharacterSet.alphanumerics` contains `129172` characters in total, but only `62` are *truly* allowed when this set is passed to a string's `addingPercentEncoding(allowedSet:)` method.

A quick way to inspect all the truly allowed characters in a particular `CharacterSet` can be done like so:

```
func inspect(charSet: CharacterSet) {
    var characters: [String] = []
    for char: UInt8 in 0..<128 { // ASCII range
        let u = UnicodeScalar(char)
        if charSet.contains(u) {
            characters.append(String(u))
        }
    }
    print("Characters:", characters.count)
    print(characters)
}

inspect(charSet: .alphanumerics) // [a-z, A-Z, 0-9]
```

This is handy as you can't simply iterate through a `CharacterSet`. It can be useful to know what those allowed elements are. For example, the predefined `CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed` only says:

> Returns the character set for characters allowed in a query URL
> component.

We can know what those allowed characters are:

```
inspect(charSet: .urlQueryAllowed)

// Characters: 81
// ["!", "$", "&", "\'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ":", ";", "=", "?", "@", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "_", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "~"]
```

**Just For Fun**

There's another (long, sure-fire) way, which looks at *all* the characters in the set (not just the ASCII ones), and compares a string of the character itself, with the string after adding percent encoding with only that character in the allowed set. When those two are equal then you know it really is an allowed character. Code adapted from [this](https://medium.com/livefront/understanding-swifts-characterset-5a7a89a32b54) helpful article.

```
func inspect(charSet: CharacterSet) {
    var characters: [String] = []
    var allowed: [String] = []
    var asciiCount = 0
    for plane: UInt8 in 0..<17 {
        if charSet.hasMember(inPlane: plane) {
            let planeStart = UInt32(plane) << 16
            let nextPlaneStart = (UInt32(plane) + 1) << 16
            for char: UTF32Char in planeStart..<nextPlaneStart {
                if let u = UnicodeScalar(char), charSet.contains(u) {
                    let s = String(u)
                    characters.append(s)
                    
                    if s.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet([u])) == s {
                        allowed.append(s)
                    }
                    
                    if u.isASCII {
                        asciiCount += 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    print("Characters:", characters.count)
    print("Allowed:", allowed.count)
    print("ASCII:", asciiCount)
}

inspect(charSet: .alphanumerics)

// Characters: 129172
// Allowed: 62
// ASCII: 62
```